# How to check for different root nodes efficiently

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I've got an ASP.NET (VB) user control that I am going to be loading an XML document into. This document could have one of two possible root node names. I have 3 possible xsl files that will need to be prepended in the xml file through the .NET. Adding the xsl reference is not a problem but I'm running into an issue determining WHICH xsl file to add.

The first thing I need to determine, after I load the XML document is what is the root node. It can be either

```
<Document xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <templateId root="usetemplate_1" />
```

or

```
<Document xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <templateId root="usetemplate_2" />
```

or

```
<Record xmlns="urn:astm-org:REC">
  <objectId>useobjectid</objectId>
```

Take note that the first two have one namespace and the third has a different namespace (not sure how to reconcile that in my brain yet either).

Each one of these options has a different xsl file to be referenced. I've got similar code in another place that I can reuse, as I said, it's just a matter of determining the right file to reference. I've got this so far:

```
Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node As XmlNode
m_xmld = New XmlDocument
m_xmld.Load(Me.XMLFileName)

Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:hl7-org:v3")
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("x:Document/", nsmgr)

For Each m_node In m_nodelist
Next
```

I'm just at a loss as to what to put between the for each/next lines to determine which one from the options above or if that is even necessary and can be done more efficiently a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```vb
Dim m_xmld As New XmlDocument()
m_xmld.Load(Me.XMLFileName)
Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("h", "urn:hl7-org:v3")
nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "urn:astm-org:REC")
If m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("/h:Document/h:templateId[@root='usetemplate_1']", nsmgr) IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Use xsl A
ElseIf m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("/h:Document/h:templateId[@root='usetemplate_2']", nsmgr) IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Use xsl B
ElseIf m_xmld.SelectSingleNode("/a:Record/a:objectId", nsmgr) IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Use xsl C
End If
```

Or, if a `Select Case` makes more sense, you can get the value of the attribute, like this:

```vb
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/h:Document/h:templateId/@root", nsmgr)
If root IsNot Nothing Then
    Select Case root.InnerText
        Case "usetemplate_1"
            ' Use xsl A
        Case "usetemplate_2"
            ' Use xsl B
    End Select
ElseIf doc.SelectSingleNode("/a:Record/a:objectId", nsmgr) IsNot Nothing Then
    ' Use xsl C
End If
```

You can add as many namespaces as you want to the namespace manager.  Even if the namespaces don't actually get used anywhere in the XML document, that won't be a problem.  So, as you can see, you can add both potential namespaces at the same time.

Comment: So I don't need the For-each/next? That does seem more efficient. I was stumped on how to do the IsNot Nothing so this helps immensely

Comment: No, you don't need the `For Each` loop, unless you need that for some unrelated reason.  The `SelectSingleNode` method returns only the first matching node.  Since you never expect there to be more than one, or even if there was more than one, it wouldn't alter your decision, there's no reason to use `SelectNodes` to get a list.  All you care about is the first one, so just use `SelectSingleNode`.  If it finds a matching node, it returns the `XmlNode` object.  If there isn't a matching node, it returns `Nothing`.